# Search for '$' using RegexQuery (NOT any other) in a Lucene index

Tags: java, lucene

I have the following program:

```
public class RegexQueryExample {

    public static String[] terms = {
        "US $65M dollars",
        "USA",
        "$35",
        "355",
        "US $33",
        "U.S.A",
        "John Keates",
        "Tom Dick Harry",
        "Southeast' Asia"
    };
    private static Directory directory;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CorruptIndexException, IOException {
        String searchString = ".*\\$.*";
        createIndex();
        searchRegexIndex(searchString);
    }

    /**
     * Creates an index for the files in the data directory.
     */
    private static void createIndex() throws CorruptIndexException, LockObtainFailedException, IOException {

        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);
        directory = new RAMDirectory();
        IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);


        for (String term : terms) {
            Document document = new Document();
            if (term.indexOf('$') >= 0) {
                document.add(new Field("type", "currency", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
            } else {
                document.add(new Field("type", "simple_field", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
            }
            document.add(new Field("term", term, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
            indexWriter.addDocument(document);
        }

        indexWriter.close();
    }

    /**
     * searches for a regular expression satisfied by a file path.
     *
     * @param searchString the string to be searched.
     */
    private static void searchRegexIndex(String regexString) throws CorruptIndexException, IOException {
        regexString = regexString;
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory);

        RegexQuery rquery = new RegexQuery(new Term("term", regexString));
        BooleanQuery queryin = new BooleanQuery();
        BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
        query.add(new TermQuery(new Term("type", "simple_field")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        query.add(rquery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

        TopDocs hits = searcher.search(query, terms.length);
        ScoreDoc[] alldocs = hits.scoreDocs;
        for (int i = 0; i < alldocs.length; i++) {
            Document d = searcher.doc(alldocs[i].doc);
            System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + d.get("term"));
        }
    }
}
```

The `createIndex()` function creates the Lucene index while `searchRegexIndex()` performs a regex query. In the `main()` function I search for `.*\\$.*` expecting it to return the terms containing the `$` sign. But, it did not work. How do I make it work? Is this some problem with the Analyzer?

**Edit:**

My Lucene index snapshot from Luke:

[image: Lucene Index]

Comment: Take a look at what RegexpCapabilities are you currently using, sounds like prefixes might not be supported. Currently I can't test your code but taking a look at the terms you've indexed it looks like your regexp might not be currently supported by the default RegexpCapabilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using StandardAnalyzer, which removes the dollar signs from the tokens. E.g. "US $65M dollars" becomes three tokens: "us", "65m", "dollars". You need to use another analyzer that does not remove the dollar signs. [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) provides an excellent analyzer tool in which you can try out different analyzers and check their outputs.

Comment: Do you know if I can use Luke for RegexQuery. I opened my index in Luke and in the search interface I cannot find an option for regex query. It seems that it creates queries from `QueryParser` :(

Comment: I have updated my Question to include snapshot of index as seen in Luke. The `$` signs are still present in the index (probably because I did not analyze the terms)

Comment: You're right, Luke uses QueryParser, which doesn't support RegexQuery. Sorry. But regarding your code, change "simple_field" to "currency" at this line: `query.add(new TermQuery(new Term("type", "simple_field")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);`